# Angular js in Dynamically create controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application one block is loaded with the controls dynamically. After loading the dynamic controls the data is update by using the angular js. But the angular js is working with static placed controls. But not with dynamic controls.

Here I placing the dynamic code What I tried to get.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#ren").html('<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>');
    });
});
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<div id="ren"></div>
<p ng-bind="name"></p>

</div>


<button>click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the input control dynamically added to the div. The text I enter in control does not appering on paragraph. But this work fine if the input control place in div static.

Am I doing any wrongly. please solve my problem.

Comment: You're using your jQuery when document is ready so your <input> will not get compiled with angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to do it in angular way, rather than mixing jQuery with angular. Because directly adding `DOM` to angular context will not worked as angular compiled DOM(means angular binding will not work on newly injected DOM). You need to compile that DOM with `$compile` service with specific `scope` before injecting it into DOM to enable binding on it.

Lets follow this way, which is fully angular way of doing it. There would be `ng-click` directive on the button, and will toggle a flag to show and hide element & we will render that array using `ng-if`

**HTML**

```
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
   <div id="ren">
     <p ng-if="showName">Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
   </div>
   <p ng-bind="name"></p>
 </div>
<button type="button" ng-click="showName!=showName">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your html attached via jquery function, is not registered to angular's watch tree. as a result, it doesn't trigger a digest cycle when you type to input with ng-model. Also this kind of usages angular with jquery in the dom edition level is not recommended. In my opinion, you should use directive instead of that jquery-dom operation